# PyCharm Displaying Traceback Object, But Not Actual Traceback

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm running a unit test in Pycharm (2022.1 Community) and getting the response below.

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: builtins.tuple: (<class 'KeyError'>, KeyError('APP_SETTINGS',), <traceback object at 0x7f8be83a1988>)
```

Any ideas why it giving "traceback object" rather than outputting the actual traceback?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set the interpreter and environment variables in the autodetect configuration template.

I initially only had these set in the unit test configuration template.

That worked for a while, but the problem is back...

Comment: Can you give more details on how you fixed it?

Comment: No, sorry, this was over a year a ago and I don't remember it that well :(